# Htaccess redirect Laravel 4

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 installation, and I used the boilerplate's htaccess to redirect my site from:

`site.com.br` to `www.site.com.br` (notice the **www**).

But when I use a route such as `site.com.br/TITLE-OF-MY-POST` I am redirected to:

`www.site.com.br/index.php` instead of `www.site.com.br/TITLE-OF-MY-POST"`

Does anyone know why? Here my htaccess rules:

Laravel's rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Boilerplate's rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change order of your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

In general keep your 301 rules before your internal rewrite rules.