# htaccess with laravel 4 rewrite on my localhost URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, laravel, laravel-4

I use this solution for my problem of htaccess : [Htaccess redirect Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837257/htaccess-redirect-laravel-4)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's very nice but it rewritten my local url : `localhost:8888/` => `www.localhost:888/`

I tryed to add :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
```

But it not working 
How do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help but it isn't working. www is always here.

Comment: OK see updated code and make sure to test in a new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Yes i tested on new browser

Comment: In that you might have some other code/framework/rule forcing this.

Comment: My framework is Laravel 4, i don't see that it can be

Comment: Well above rule by definition cannot redirect localhost to `www.localhost` so that has to be something behind the scenes. And I have tested this rule myself before posting.

Comment: I new tested and it's oki, Thanks.